# How to get ufw(8)-like (Uncomplicated Firewall) functionality for macOS firewall?

Tags: macos, ssh, vpn, firewall, network

How can I get [ufw(8)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)-like (Linux [Uncomplicated Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall)) functionality for macOS firewall?

[ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) enables per-IP-address/subnets and per-IP-port configuration. I see no way to do this with macOS [sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Wst.png) and [firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzRh6.png) System Preferences functionality, example screenshots below.

My primary use case: I want to enable a VPN (it happens to be implemented via [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/), but I do not want to get distracted with "VPN religion") between my MacBooks like what my team does with Linux servers and Windows/macOS/Linux clients, and there needs to be a "VPN port" and the private-IP-addr VPN subnet open on the firewall; here's an example Linux-server-side ufw status (192.168.101.x is the "private VPN subnet" and 11223 is the WireGuard IP port):

```
$ ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.101.0/24            
11223/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
11223/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

$
```

I want to do something similar on the macOS side to provide a better, more-granular security (over what the default System Preferences offer) for something ssh-logging-into a macOS laptop. (Namely: so I can rsync(1) between macOS laptops.)

I'm running macOS 10.14.6:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G1012
$
```

[image: System.Preferences.sharing]
[image: System.Preferences.firewall]

Comment: See `pfctl(8)` and `pf.conf(5)` for this functionality. Here is a good [comprehensive guide](https://gist.github.com/flackend/7c999c943ab46f4bfe34).